# Nothing showing up on my LogLogPlots

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I am trying to make 2 log log plots. One with each equation, a and g. I don't know why, but the plot is not showing up. My notebook is in the link below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc93L.jpg

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You can't plot imaginary numbers on a real number line - try removing the *i* in your functions.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
a[f_] := 25000/(1 + (I*f)/200)

ReImPlot[a[f], {f, 0.1, 10000}, PlotRange -> All,
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {.35, .6}]]
```

[image]

```
LogLogPlot[Abs[a[f]], {f, 0.1, 10000}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]